# How can I allow only numbers, one comma, and two digits after the comma in my input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field, that only allows numbers and one point.

```js
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
       ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
       (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
           event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
        (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }      
});
```

```css
.number {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number" />
```

I want to use this for currency so instead of the point I need to have a comma. So I replaced every point into the function with a comma. But it is not working.

```js
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf(',') != -1) &&
       ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
       (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
           event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf(',') == -1)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf(',')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf(',') + 3));
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    if ((text.indexOf(',') != -1) &&
        (text.substring(text.indexOf(',')).length > 2) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }      
});
```

```css
.number {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change 46 to 44, in order to allow commas instead of full stops...

```js
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // this next line...
    if ((event.which != 44 || $this.val().indexOf(',') != -1) &&
       ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
       (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
           event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    // this next line...
    if ((event.which == 44) && (text.indexOf(',') == -1)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf(',')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf(',') + 3));
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    if ((text.indexOf(',') != -1) &&
        (text.substring(text.indexOf(',')).length > 2) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }      
});
```

```css
.number {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number" />
```

The two lines I marked detect the user pressing the full stop key, and allows it (along with any numbers), but blocks everything else.  46 is the ASCII value for a full stop so it just needed changing to 44, which is the ASCII value for a comma.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I didn't know that. Now it makes sense :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Happy to help :)

Comment: wow. never new event.preventDefault() is so useful when it comes to blocking new insertions into input field. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to replace the number 46 (.), with 44(,);

```js
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((event.which != 44 || $this.val().indexOf(',') != -1) &&
       ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
       (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
           event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which == 44) && (text.indexOf(',') == -1)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf(',')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf(',') + 3));
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    if ((text.indexOf(',') != -1) &&
        (text.substring(text.indexOf(',')).length > 2) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }      
});
```

```css
.number {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number" />
```